# How to submit custom spark application on Azure Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-hdinsight, azure-databricks

I have created a small application that submits a spark job at certain intervals and creates some analytical reports. These jobs can read data from a local filesystem or a distributed filesystem (fs could be HDFS, ADLS or WASB). Can I run this application on Azure databricks cluster?

The application works fine on HDInsights cluster as I was able to access the nodes. I kept my deployable jar at one location, started it using the start-script similarly I could also stop it using the stop-script that I prepared.

One thing I found is that Azure Databricks has its own File System: ADFS, I can also add support for this file system but then will I be able to deploy and run my application as I was able to do it on the HDInsight cluster? If not, is there a way I can submit jobs from an edge node, my HDInsight cluster or any other OnPrem Cluster to Azure Databricks cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Jobs? https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/jobs.html. You can submit jars to spark-submit just like on HDInsight.

Databricks file system is DBFS - ABFS is used for Azure Data Lake. You should not need to modify your application for these - the file paths will be handled by databricks.